# How to Autowire LdapRepository in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-ldap

I am attempting to use Spring's auto-configuration to spin up an embedded LDAP server and access it using spring-data-ldap.  However, the autowired fields,  repository (an instance of LdapRepository) and the ldapTemplate (an instance of the LdapTemplate) are null.

For example,

```
spring.ldap.model.UserTest > testSaveUser FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at UserTest.java:32
```

What am I missing?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.6.RELEASE' apply false
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-ldap'
  compile 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'
  testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
  testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Under src/main/java/spring/ldap/model:

Config.java

package spring.ldap.model;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.config.EnableLdapRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories
public class Config { }
```

User.java

```
package spring.ldap.model;

import javax.naming.Name;

import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Attribute;
import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.DnAttribute;
import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry;
import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Id;

@Entry(objectClasses = { "person", "top" }, base="dc=spring,dc=ldap,dc=model" )
public class User {
  @Id private Name dn;
  @Attribute(name = "cn") @DnAttribute(value = "cn", index = 0) private String userName;
  @Attribute(name = "sn") private String fullName;

  public Name getDn() { return dn; }
  public void setDn(Name dn) { this.dn = dn; }

  public String getUsername() { return userName; }
  public void setUsername(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

  public String getFullName() { return fullName; }
  public void setFullName(String fullName) { this.fullName = fullName; }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package spring.ldap.model;

import org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends LdapRepository<User> { }
```

Under src/test/java/spring/ldap/model:

UserTest.java

```
package spring.ldap.model;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import javax.naming.Name;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.ldap.DataLdapTest;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapNameBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@DataLdapTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class UserTest {
  @Autowired UserRepository repository;
  @Autowired LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

  @Before
  public void SetUp() {
    LdapNameBuilder builder = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance();
    builder.add("dc", "model");
    builder.add("dc", "ldap");
    builder.add("dc", "spring");
    Name dn = builder.build();
    DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);
    context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "domain", "extensibleObject" });
    context.setAttributeValue("dc", "spring");
    ldapTemplate.bind(context);
  }

  @Test public void testSaveUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("ncornish");
    user.setFullName("Nicholas Cornish");

    repository.save(user);

    assertNotNull("Id was not generated!", user.getDn());
  }
}
```

Under src/test/resources:

application.properties

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=spring,dc=ldap,dc=model
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username=uid=admin
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password=secret
```

Comment: Your test doesn't run into a Spring context, since it's not annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. So nothing will never autowire anything inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks JB Nezit, your comment

> Your test doesn't run into a Spring context, since it's not annotated
>   with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class). So nothing will ever autowire
>   anything inside it.

resolves the issue.  ie. add the following to the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Must put these annotations on test class context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserRepository.class, LdapTemplate.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```

Kind regards.